# Is it possible to combine adding and subtracting into one function?

Tags: javascript

I have these two buttons, one that calls `minus(val)` and the other calls `plus(val)` function.

```
function minus(val) {
    val <= 1 ? width = 1 : width = val - 1;
}

function plus(val) {
    val >= 5 ? width = 5 : width = val + 1;
}
```

Is it possible to combine both these functions into one? So I can just call one function on each button, like `changeValue(val);`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try not to perform assignments *within* ternary statements - in this case, you'd probably want something like `width = val >= 5 ? 5 : val + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine both these functions into one?

No. They do different things, e.g. when you call them with the value `3`.

You can see that better if you simplify them to

```
function minus(val) {
    width = Math.max(1, val - 1);
}
function plus(val) {
    width = Math.min(5, val + 1);
}
```

Of course you might use a function with a second parameter that decides what to do. It could be

```
function changeValue(val, dir) {
    width = Math.min(5, Math.max(1, val + dir));
}
```

that you could call both as `changeValue(val, +1)` and `changeValue(val, -1)`.

Or right away, with a more descriptive name:

```
limitedWidth(val) {
    width = Math.min(5, Math.max(1, val));
}
// limitedWidth(val + 1)
// limitedWidth(val - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeValue(val){
  if(val > 5){ };
  else if(val < 1){ };
}
```

Can you get the rest?